# Calling functions, within functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have this Script, that im using as a learning thing. In this code im trying to have it, so that each time the button is clicked, it will run multiple codes. Such as each time it will lose 1 stamina, change either 1 of 3 things (Money,stamina, or health) and then update the number on the screen. Unfortunately.. My number is not updating. I had this program work before with just calling one function but now i have multiple, its causing problems.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var stam=100;
var cash=0;
var health=100;
var rNumber=Math.random();
function explore(){      //2<- This function gets called and runs two functions
    if(stam>1){
        redStam();
        refresh();
              //<-- will add a function to use a random number later to decide whether health, money or stamina gets changed.
    };
    else{alert("You have no stamina")}}   
    function refresh(){   //3<-This function gets called, which refreshes the current variables
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=stam;
    };
    function redStam(){   //3<This function also gets called. 
        stam--;
    };
</script>
<button onclick="explore()">Explore</button>            1<- button gets clicked
</head>
<body>
<p id='number'>100</P>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Also, note that function declarations require (), for example, function redStam() {}

Comment: I started editing this for formatting but there are so many syntax errors I'm not sure I'd make it any better. OP, please properly indent your code and ensure you're posting at least syntactically valid code...whether or not it works.

Comment: Just added the problem to the post.. I have also just changed the my code to have () in my functions, but the code still isnt working

Comment: Have you checked the console, did you find any exceptions/errors?

Comment: Why is there a `<button>` in the `<head>`?

Comment: @Ian, Has been moved, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement has an unneeded semicolon: `if { ... }; else { ... }`.

Try checking the console for your browser when you encounter a JavaScript error. It will tell what line the problem is on.

Comment: After removing my semi colons, and adding () which was suggested in the previous comments, it appears to have been fixed. I will look into using the console for future, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of syntax errors, check your console, and you have the semicolon after the `if`.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmyNc/) seems to be working.

```
function explore() { //2<- This function gets called and runs two functions
    if (stam > 1) {
        redStam();
        refresh(); 
    } else {
        alert("You have no stamina")
    }
}
```